# Prove that $L^p(\Omega) \subset L^q (\Omega)$ whenever $\Omega$ is a bounded open set and $1 ≤ q ≤ p ≤ +\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $\Omega$ be  a bounded open set and $1 ≤ q ≤ p ≤ +\infty$.   Prove that $L^p(\Omega) \subset L^q (\Omega)$.  Where $L^p(\Omega)$ and $L^q(\Omega)$  are the spaces of functions $f$ for which $|f|^p$ and $|f|^q$ is integrable.

In trying to solve this, many books refer me to Holder's inequality.  However, I have failed to connect it to this problem.

Comment: Write $|f|^{q}$ as $(1) (|f|^{q})$  and apply Holder with conjugate indices $\frac  p q$ and $\frac p {p-q}$.

Comment: A bounded open set where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $(X,\mu)$ is a measure space with $\mu(X)<\infty.$ Assume $0<q<p<\infty$ (the case $p=\infty$ is very simple). Let $f\ge 0,$ with $f\in L^p(X).$ Set $A=\{f\le 1\}, B = \{f> 1\}.$ Then

$$\int_X f^q\,d\mu = \int_A f^q\,d\mu + \int_B f^q\,d\mu \le \mu(A) + \int_B f^p\,d\mu <\infty.$$

Comment: Why the downvote? This is easiest solution to this problem that I know of.